# Unable to wake display with remote

Tags: sleep, remote-control, xbmc

I'm running an HTPC (xbmc) without a keyboard/mouse attached, running oneiric.  After some indeterminate amount of time, sometime between 1 and 12 hours, the display goes to sleep.  The computer itself is not sleeping, I can still SSH to it from another computer.  The remote will not wake the display.  The IR receiver is working, as `irw` will show me the remote key presses.  The only way to get my display back is to restart the display manager, lightdm in this case.

Does anybody know a way to keep the display from going to sleep?  I don't really need any power management at all considering that it connects to my TV and when I want my display to go to sleep, I turn off my TV.

Answer (score 1):

It MIGHT be screensaver related. If you run XBMC from Gnome (or similar), you can try (for 11.10):

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type=bool false
```

Or for 12.04:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

If you are running XBMC in its own session (you log in to xbmc from lightdm) you might be experiencing the same problem as me: [How do I disable the screen saver in 12.04 system wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135531/how-do-i-disable-the-screen-saver-in-12-04-system-wide)

Comment: Yeah, lightdm launches it directly.  I've tried all of these solutions before though, so I'm back to the drawing board.  Thanks anyway.